# Saving randomly generated passwords to a text file in order to display them later

Tags: c++-cli, clr

I'm currently in a traineeship and I currently have to softwares I'm working on. The most important was requested yesterday and I'm stucked on the failure of its main feature: *saving passwords*.

The application is developped in C++\CLR using Visual Studio 2013 (Couldn't install MFC libraries somehow, installation kept failing and crashing even after multiple reboots.) and aims to generate a password from a seed provided by the user. The generated password will be save onto a .txt file. If the seed has already been used then the previously generated password will show up.

Unfortunately I can't save the password and seed to the file, though I can write the seed *if* I don't get to the end of the document. I went for the "if line is empty then write this to the document" but it doesn't work and I can't find out why. However I can read the passwords without any problem.

Here's the interresting part of the source:

```
int seed;
char genRandom() {
    static const char letters[] =
        "0123456789"
        "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    int stringLength = sizeof(letters) - 1;
    return letters[rand() % stringLength];
}
System::Void OK_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    fstream passwords;
    if (!(passwords.is_open())) {
        passwords.open("passwords.txt", ios::in | ios::out);
    }
    string gen = msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(GENERATOR->Text), line, genf = gen;
    bool empty_line_found = false;
    while (empty_line_found == false) {
        getline(passwords, line);
        if (gen == line) {
            getline(passwords, line);
            PASSWORD->Text = msclr::interop::marshal_as<System::String^>(line);
            break;
        }
        if (line.empty()) {
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < gen.length(); i++) {
                seed += gen[i];
            }
            srand(seed);
            string pass;
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
                pass += genRandom();
            }
            passwords << pass << endl << gen << "";
            PASSWORD->Text = msclr::interop::marshal_as<System::String^>(pass);
            empty_line_found = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I've also tried replacing `ios::in` by `ios::app` and it doesn't work. And yes I have included fstream, iostream, etc.

Thanks in advance!

***[EDIT]***
Just solved this problem. Thanks Rook for putting me on the right way. It feels like a silly way to do it, but I've closed the file and re-openned it using ios::app to write at the end of it. I also solved a stupid mistake resulting in writing the password before the seed and not inserting a final line so the main loop can still work. Here's the code in case someone ends up with the same problem:

```
int seed;
char genRandom() {
    static const char letters[] =
        "0123456789"
        "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    int stringLength = sizeof(letters) - 1;
    return letters[rand() % stringLength];
}
System::Void OK_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    fstream passwords;
    if (!(passwords.is_open())) {
        passwords.open("passwords.txt", ios::in | ios::out);
    }
    string gen = msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(GENERATOR->Text), line, genf = gen;
    bool empty_line_found = false;
    while (empty_line_found == false) {
        getline(passwords, line);
        if (gen == line) {
            getline(passwords, line);
            PASSWORD->Text = msclr::interop::marshal_as<System::String^>(line);
            break;
        }
        if (line.empty()) {
            passwords.close();
            passwords.open("passwords.txt", ios::app);
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < gen.length(); i++) {
                seed += gen[i];
            }
            srand(seed);
            string pass;
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
                pass += genRandom();
            }
            passwords << gen << endl << pass << endl << "";
            PASSWORD->Text = msclr::interop::marshal_as<System::String^>(pass);
            empty_line_found = true;
        }
    }
    passwords.close();
}
```

Comment: Writing applications in C++-CLI is a terrible, terrible idea. Use it only for glue code, so you can use C++ stuff in a managed application. Write the rest of your managed code in C#  (or other CLR language) and your development will be faster and simpler and your life will be easier.

Comment: (or if you're wedded to C++, write a nice simple command line application and avoid messing around with huge UI libraries and language extensions)

Comment: "_ I can write the seed if I don't get to the end of the document_" implies that you're hitting an EOF, and not clearing the status flags of your file stream, so it will refuse to accept any more input. I'd also avoid formatted writes to a file you're still reading from, but that's just me.

Comment: Well the problem is that I don't know anything about C#, and I have to create an application that isn't a console app. The other project I'm working on, also in CLI, is doing fine.

Comment: @PointR: If you're successfully made a C++/CLI application with a GUI, you know more about C# than you realize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, here's an interesting thing:

```
passwords << pass << endl << gen << "";
```

You're not ending that with a newline. This means the very end of your file *could* be missing a newline too. This has an interesting effect when you do this on the final line:

```
getline(passwords, line);
```

`getline` will read until it sees a line ending, or an EOF. If there's no newline, it'll hit that EOF and then set the EOF bit on the stream. That means the next time you try to do this:

```
passwords << pass << endl << gen << "";
```

the stream will refuse to write anything, because it is in an eof state. There are various things you can do here, but the simplest would be to do `passwords.clear()` to remove any error flags like eof. I'd be very cautious about accidentally clearing genuine error flags though; read the docs for `fstream` carefully.

I also reiterate my comment about C++/CLR being a glue language, and not a great language for general purpose development, which would be best done using C++ or a .net language, such as C#. If you're absolutely wedded to C++/CLR for some reason, you may as well make use of the extensive .net library so you don't have to pointlessly martial managed types back and forth. See [System::IO::FileStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream(v=vs.110).aspx) for example.